# I want to reduce the width and height of this box, it's not an image only a box How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

```
{<html> <head> <body> <table border="1"> <tr> <td> personal </td> </tr> </body> </head> </html>
```

Comment: I want to change the size of personal box in html.

Comment: We are going to need to see some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do inline styles for those elements.
For example:

```
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

But you should really use CSS which you can declare at the inside the the  tags in your html

```
    <head>
       <style>
            div {
               width: 100px;
               height: 100px;
            }
       </style>
    </head>
```

You can find more information on CSS if your just starting out at w3schools.com

Comment: {<html> <head> <body> <table border="1"> <tr> <td> personal </td> </tr> </body> </head> </html>
comment: i want to change the size of personal box in html

Comment: Then you can add the width and the heights directly to the <td> if you want it to be even around the words you could add "padding:50px".

Comment: PatricKelly your code don't execute

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you just tried, I will be able to help better then.